# Execute SQL statements with Autotools

Tags: mysql, autotools

I'm writing a library of MySQL UDF. The build system is based on `GNU Autotools`. The compilation and installation of the shared library itself works well.
However to use the UDF, we need to execute some SQL statements as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/udf-compiling.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION metaphon RETURNS STRING SONAME 'udf_example.so';
```

The current `Makefile.am` contains an explicit rule:

```
installdb: 
    $(MYSQL) <./installdb.sql
```

where `./installdb.sql` contains the `CREATE FUNCTION` statements.
However, it doesn't work when building outside of source tree and the user must call `make installdb` explicitly (while I would like it to be part of `make install`).

Any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The current Makefile.am contains an explicit rule:
>
> ```
> installdb: 
>     $(MYSQL) <./installdb.sql
> ```
>
> where `./installdb.sql` contains the `CREATE FUNCTION` statements.
>   However, it doesn't work when building outside of source tree

Supposing that `installdb.sql` is a file included in the package distribution, not a built one, no, that wouldn't work in an out-of-source build, because "`./installdb.sql`" would not then refer to an existing file.  If you want a build recipe to refer to a file that is neither a rule prerequisite nor a target built by some other rule, then you cannot expect magic -- you need to specify the wanted file via a usable path.  The same applies even to prerequisites if you refer to them explicitly in your build rules. `VPATH` builds operate via `make`'s automatic variables, such as `$<` and `$^`.

And GNU `make` has a solution to that.  The path to the source-tree directory corresponding to the current `make`'s working directory is always available via the `$(srcdir)` variable.  Using that, your recipe would look more like this:

```
installdb: 
    $(MYSQL) < $(srcdir)/installdb.sql
```

For an in-source build, `$(srcdir)` will evaluate to `.`, so in that case the above is equivalent to what you started with.  For an out-of-source build, `$(srcdir)` will contain the appropriate path.

Occasionally, it is also useful to reference the root of the source tree.  For instance, you might want to refer to files in a direct subdirectory of the source root, without introducing other dependencies on source-tree structure.  For that, you can use `$(top_srcdir)` to refer to the source tree root.

These details are not clearly covered in the current Automake docs, but you can find them in [other GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Basics.html).

> and the
>   user must call `make installdb` explicitly (while I would like it to be
>   part of `make install`).

Well, yes, Automake does not assume that every target for which you provide a rule has to be exercised by a `make install`.  Not even all the targets it generates itself are exercised that way.  But Automake does have mechanisms for indicating which user-provided rules should be included, and at what point.  The current manual covers this in [section 23.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending.html#Extending).

In your case, I would use an installation hook, either by renaming your target to `install-data-hook` or by declaring a new target of that name, and making your `installdb` target a prerequisite.  The latter would look like this:

```
install-data-hook: installdb
```

The former has stronger promises about timing, however, so if it were critical that the database initialization be performed near the end of the installation, then it would be better to do the target name change in the hook's own recipe:

```
install-data-hook: 
    $(MYSQL) < $(srcdir)/installdb.sql
```

Either way, do also consider what, if any, corresponding *un*installation rules may be needed.  Also, if you retain your separate `installdb` target, then it would be good form to mark it as phony:

```
PHONY = installdb
```

That avoids breakage in the event that an actual file of that name happens to be in the build directory for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @John-Bollinger. I knew I need to do something along the lines of what you said but I couldn't find clear documentation.